# Cannot remove server in response headers (Amazon AWS)

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, http, amazon-web-services, http-headers

I cannot remove the "Server" header from the response headers. I am using Amazon EC2. I have added this in Apache config:

ServerSignature Off
Header unset Server
RequestHeader unset Server

It does not do anything. I can still see the server header saying "Apache (Amazon)" in the response headers. Any clue?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes I have several times

Answer (score 6):

You can not unset the Server response header. Though, it is not required by HTTP RFC, the Apache httpd developers are not in favor of allowing it to be completely removed. So, unless you want to modify source and compile, it's going to be there. Also you probably want to look at the [ServerTokens](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens) directive.

Apache bugzilla entry is [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40026)

Comment: That is not cool.